# Crash during inputting data ACS, Now I can't se my data anymore

Tags: appcelerator, backend, appcelerator-acs

As so many times before, I was putting data into my ACS Admin. All of A sudden I couldn't save a post, and upon reload nothing happened. Following I can't see any of my data from the posts table in ACS.

Have anybody experienced the same or have any idea what could be wrong?

Kind regards
Søren Thorup
Denmark

Comment: This doesn't seem like an issue the community will be able to help you with. Please contact support@appcelerator.com

Comment: Already have, and it seems like they have found a solution. Now I have a new problem with the ACS, but i guess I'll write them on the mail you posted. Thank you Fokke :-)